# extra space after parsing a string with regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have the following simple code:

```
String d = "_|,|\\.";
String s1 = "b,_a_.";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(d);
String[] ss = p.split(s1);
for (String str : ss){
     System.out.println(str.trim());
}
```

The output gives

```
b

a
```

Where does the extra space come from between b and a?

Comment: `String[] ss = "b,_a_.".split("[,_.]+");` should work

Comment: There is no extra space. You are seeing the splits. Take out your ORs and walk through it one option at a time, e.g., "_" or "," and then "_|," and you should see it build up with splits with newlines at those points.

Answer (score 3):

You do not have an extra space, you get an empty element in the resulting array because your regex matches *only 1* character, and when there are several characters from the set on end, the string is split at each of those characters.

Thus, you should match as many of those characters in your character class as possible with `+` (1 or more) quantifier by placing the whole expression into a non-capturing group (`(?:_|,|\\.)+`), or - better - using a character class `[_,.]+`:

```
String d = "(?:_|,|\\.)+"; // Or better: String d = "[_,.]+";
String s1 = "b,_a_.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(d);
String[] ss = p.split(s1);
for (String str : ss){
    System.out.println(str.trim());
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/zxPvJx)

Comment: Caveat: [`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) doc says "Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array", *but* leading empty strings are, so a value of `,b,_a_.` will start with an empty value. Only way to fix that is to skip it yourself (or trim before splitting, but skip is better/faster).

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, as for the currently provided input, this empty element appears when splitting in the middle. Indeed, `String[] ss = p.split(s1.trim());` is preferable in case there can be any leading spaces. And the `trim()` in the `for` cycle can be redundant if we use `String d = "\\s*[_,.]+\\s*";` after matching all whitespace around the delimiters.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the `trim()` function, because that won't eliminate a leading `,` anyway. Besides I said not to, just skip the empty value in the `for` loop.

Comment: thanks for the help and explanation. I have not had much experience with regular expression.  For some reason, it has been more perplexing to me than understanding recursion.

Comment: @user2001996: Do not give up, basic regex notions are not that difficult. BTW, I strongly advise using `[_,.]+` character class to alternations when you have single characters to match. Use alternations only when you have different sequences of characters to match.

Answer (score 1):

While i get puzzled my self, maybe what you want is to change your regex to

```
String d = "[_,\\.]+";
```